# SelectionSort in Php with Destructuring

Tags: php

I''m trying to do a SelectionSort in PHP, but is not sorting as i expect, what could be wrong?

```
<?php

$grades = [5, 2, 10, 5, 1, 7];
$selectionSort = function ($array) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
        $min = $i;
        for ($j = $i + 1; $j < count($array); $j++) {
            if ($array[$j] < $array[$i]) $min = $j;
            if ($i !== $min) [$array[$i], $array[$min]] = [$array[$min], $array[$i]];
        }
    };
    return $array;
};

$new = $selectionSort($grades);

foreach ($new as $item) {
    echo "<h1>" . $item . "</h1>";
}
```

Comment: What is the result?

Comment: @Milad an array that is sorted not correctly.

Comment: I know that. I mean how is it sorted? There might be a pattern in the result to find the problem quickly without deeply analyzing the code.

Comment: Did you use php `sort()` function?

Comment: @Milad you can run the code online easily, and for the second question, I want to learn sorting myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion (quite self-explanatory):

```
$grades = [5, 2, 10, 5, 1, 7];

$selectionSort = function ($array) {
    $count = count($array);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    for ($j = $i + 1; $j < $count; $j++) {
        if ($array[$i] > $array[$j]) {
            $temp = $array[$i];
            $array[$i] = $array[$j];
            $array[$j] = $temp;
        }
    }
}
    return $array;
};

$new = $selectionSort($grades);

foreach ($new as $item) {
    echo "<h1>" . $item . "</h1>";
}
```

[Demo](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/71b07679b391a5730d9833d98887d87ca47369d9)